# Where can I access Google Maps Android API v2 assets?

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm using Google Maps Android API v2 and I've added a button on top of the map. Now, I'd like to have a consistent design, so I'd like my button to look like the zoom buttons, center-on-location button. Where can I access these image files? I can make one in photoshop but that just doesn't look right because of the transparencies in the images.

Answer (score 1):

These assets are buried inside GooglePlayServices.APK and its modification and use might be restricted by the license.

As this is not a site, where lawyers answers questions, I suggest trying to make translucent images in photoshop.